# change a bootstrap radio button value in a loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am trying to change a radio button's position based on a value I get back from a mysql query. This loop runs multiple times and creates a row with each iteration.
I have tried:

```
    $("#far_table tbody").sortable("disable");
    $("#far_table > tbody").empty();
    $.getJSON("gsffar.ajax.php", {
        function: 'update_far_table',
        Engnum: engnum,
        Type: type_toggle,
        Travid: travid
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(data).each(function()
        {
            $("#far_table").append('<tr> \
                                <td class="priority">' + this.priority + '</td> \
                                <td>' + this.attribute + '</td>\
                                <td>' + this.responsible + '</td> \
                                <td><div class="btn-group" id="pass_fail_group" data-toggle="buttons">\
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary active">\
                                        <input class="pass_fail" type="radio" name="options" id="pass" value="pass"> Pass\
                                    </label>\
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary" active>\
                                        <input class="pass_fail" type="radio" name="options" id="fail" value="fail" checked> Fail\
                                    </label>\
                                </div></td>\
                                <td><div class="input-group">\
                                <div class="custom-file">\
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">\
                                </div>\
                                </div></td>\
                                </tr>');

            if (this.pass_fail === "pass"){
                $('input:radio[name="options"][value="pass"]').click();
            }else{
                $('input:radio[name="options"][value="fail"]').click();
            }
            
        });
    });
}
```

and

```
function update_far_table_input(engnum, type_toggle, travid){
    $("#far_table tbody").sortable("disable");
    $("#far_table > tbody").empty();
    $.getJSON("gsffar.ajax.php", {
        function: 'update_far_table',
        Engnum: engnum,
        Type: type_toggle,
        Travid: travid
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $(data).each(function()
        {
            var pass="";
            var fail="";
            if (this.pass_fail === "pass"){
                pass="checked";
            }else{
                fail="checked";
            }

            $("#far_table").append('<tr> \
                                <td class="priority">' + this.priority + '</td> \
                                <td>' + this.attribute + '</td>\
                                <td>' + this.responsible + '</td> \
                                <td><div class="btn-group" id="pass_fail_group" data-toggle="buttons">\
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary active">\
                                        <input class="pass_fail" type="radio" name="options" id="pass" value="pass" autocomplete="off" '+pass+'> Pass\
                                    </label>\
                                    <label class="btn btn-primary">\
                                        <input class="pass_fail" type="radio" name="options" id="fail" value="fail" autocomplete="off" '+fail+'> Fail\
                                    </label>\
                                </div></td>\
                                <td><div class="input-group">\
                                <div class="custom-file">\
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">\
                                </div>\
                                </div></td>\
                                </tr>');
        });
    });
}
```

Neither approach seems to work. I would also like to add a third position in the future so being able to specify position by id or value would be ideal.

Comment: just add the property `checked` to the appropriate radio button

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to break out the building of the labels.

In this snippet I'm appending the new row and then once it's added to the table the containing div is *"jQueryable"*.

I'm taking some liberties with your data but you should be able to get the gist of it.

Be aware, Html element `id`'s should be unique.

Using this function with rows containing duplicate id's for the placeholder element is going to be a problem.

```js
$("#far_table").append('<tr>\
  <td class="priority">' + this.priority + '</td> \
  <td>' + this.attribute + '</td>\
  <td>' + this.responsible + '</td> \
  <td>\
    <div class="btn-group" id="pass_fail_group" data-toggle="buttons">\
    </div>\
  </td>\
  <td>\
    <div class="input-group">\
      <div class="custom-file">\
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" \
        id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">\
      </div>\
    </div>\
  </td>\
</tr>');

buildRadios(document.getElementById('pass_fail_group'), 'options', ['pass', 'fail'], "pass")

function buildRadios(placeholderElem, groupname, valueArray, data_pf) {
  valueArray.forEach((e, i) => {
    let active = e === data_pf;

    const lbl = document.createElement('label');
    lbl.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary")
    if (active) {
      lbl.classList.add('active');
    }
    const radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.id = e;
    radio.type = 'radio';
    radio.value = e;
    if (active) {
      radio.setAttribute("checked", "");
    }
    radio.name = groupname;
    radio.classList.add("pass_fail");

    lbl.appendChild(radio);
    let properCase = `${e.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${e.slice(1).toLowerCase()}`
    lbl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(properCase));

    placeholderElem.appendChild(lbl)
  });
}
```

```css
label.btn {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="far_table" class="w-100"></table>
```